# Why doesn't logcat capture complete stack traces in the way that Android Studio's Run view does?

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

In the following example, logcat output misses the exception needed which is seen only at the bottom of the trace in Android Studio's Run tab. Why is this? Can logcat be configured to show complete output?

Android Studio's Logcat view & logcat echoed to file:

```
05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055): with id: uk.co.foobar.tm.free.debug:id/reset_timer'.
05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055):     at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055):     at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:81)
05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055):     at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)

etc etc

05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055):     at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:472)
05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055):     at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:419)
05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055):     at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:240)
05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055):     at android
05-25 14:36:02.745 I/TestRunner(15055): ----- end exception -----
```

Android Studio's 'Run' view:

```
with id: uk.co.foobar.tm.free.debug:id/reset_timer'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:81)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)

etc etc

at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:472)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:419)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:240)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:138)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:119)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:153)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:33)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:44)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:128)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:241)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:62)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:149)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:146)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
at uk.co.foobar.state.MealyMachine.transition(MealyMachine.java:77)
at uk.co.foobar.presenter.MainPresenter.clickResetTimer(MainPresenter.java:203)
at uk.co.foobar.tm.TmActivity.clickResetTimer(TmActivity.java:1311)
... 29 more

Tests ran to completion.
```

Comment: It's probably/possibly relevant that the original `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown from a pure java library module within the app